# Facebook SDK 7.8.0 Error: get_activeBuildTarget is not allowed to be called from a ScriptableObject constructor

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine

I upgraded to the latest version of Facebook SDK 7.8.0 and I'm using **Unity 5.4.0.3f,** when I'm clicking on **Facebook button in Unity Editor**, I get a strange error:

> get_activeBuildTarget is not allowed to be called from a ScriptableObject constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in OnEnable instead. Called from ScriptableObject 'FacebookSettingsEditor'.
>       See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
>       0x0000000140E431ED (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
>       0x0000000140E44EE1 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
>       0x00000001405FC603 (Unity) GetStacktrace
>       0x00000001405F97FE (Unity) DebugStringToFile
>       0x00000001405F9C5C (Unity) DebugStringToFile
>       0x000000014035F701 (Unity) ThreadAndSerializationSafeCheckReportError
>       0x00000001413CE6D8 (Unity) EditorUserBuildSettings_Get_Custom_PropActiveBuildTarget
>       0x00000000134DFF3A (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.EditorUserBuildSettings:get_activeBuildTarget ()
>       0x000000001F75195E (Mono JIT Code) Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor:.ctor ()
>       0x000000000A4C68E2 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>       0x00007FF929D6519B (mono) [mini.c:4937] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
>       0x00007FF929CB84FD (mono) [object.c:2623] mono_runtime_invoke 
>       0x00000001403399E5 (Unity) mono_runtime_invoke_profiled
>       0x0000000140339BD1 (Unity) mono_runtime_object_init_exception
>       0x00000001403606A2 (Unity) scripting_unity_engine_object_new_and_invoke_default_constructor
>       0x0000000140343F0F (Unity) MonoBehaviour::RebuildMonoInstance
>       0x00000001403440B1 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::RebuildMonoInstanceFromScriptChange
>       0x000000014034420E (Unity) MonoBehaviour::SetClass
>       0x0000000140B85515 (Unity) IsCustomEditorDirty
>       0x0000000140B85FEA (Unity) CreateInspectorMonoBehaviour
>       0x0000000140B7BFCB (Unity) ActiveEditorTracker::Rebuild
>       0x0000000140B7C709 (Unity) ActiveEditorTracker::DidFlushDirty
>       0x0000000140C82144 (Unity) SceneTracker::FlushDirty
>       0x0000000140BD3F5E (Unity) Application::UpdateSceneIfNeeded
>       0x0000000140BDBE54 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
>       0x0000000140E3D91E (Unity) FindMonoBinaryToUse
>       0x0000000140E3EF4C (Unity) WinMain
>       0x00000001415BCA40 (Unity) strnlen
>       0x00007FF952788102 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk

Any ideas how to fix this issue :( ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does someone found solution to this problem ??

Comment: Wow, i total disagree with the above outcome, as it clearly says that he upgraded to the latest sdks and then click on Facebook login. i don't know if this will help but i believe it has to do with the latest version of unity and the compatibility.

Comment: Same problem here; tried to upgrade from the same version of Unity to the latest (5.4.1f1), but nothing changed